# "Приятно расположиться в сторону древних развалин"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис

> Здесь, на вершине крохотного холма, вы обнаружите скамеечки; впрочем,
>   приятно расположиться и прямо на склоне в сторону древних развалин...

Я что-то неправильно воспринимаю:

Это склон "в сторону древних развалин" или "расположиться  в сторону древних развалин"?

И вообще, а как правильно-то?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятно, всё же "на склоне, смотрящем в сторону древних развалин".

Или "расположиться и прямо на склоне **с видом на древние развалины..**."

Answer (score 2):

Я вижу эту картину так:
...прямо на склоне, **спускающемся** (или **сбегающем**) **в сторону** древних развалин...

Или:
..прямо на склоне, **сбегающем** (или **спускающемся**) **к** древним развалинам...

*...ботанический сад епископства. Он не самый большой во Франции, но расположен на склоне, спускающемся к Вьенне.*
*Компания расположилась на пологом травянистом склоне, сбегающем к нежно журчащей реке Ли.*